# How to create Observable out of Runnable?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Sometimes I want to trigger a `Runnable` as part of my `Observable` sequence, but the `Runnable` does not report progress.

I have written a simple factory for wrapping a `Runnable` object into an `Observable`:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> fromRunnable(final Runnable action) {
    if (action == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("action");
    }
    return Observable.fromPublisher(subscriber -> {
        try {
            action.run();
            subscriber.onComplete();
        } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            subscriber.onError(throwable);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
Observable.concat(
    someTask, 
    MoreObservables.fromRunnable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Done. ");
    }));
```

But does RxJava 2 provide this functionality already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such factory method for `Observable`, *but* `Completable` could be made from `Runnable`. So you could create a `Completable` first and then convert it to `Observable`:

```
Observable.concat(
    someTask, 
    Completable.fromRunnable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }).toObservable()
);
```

---

**Update:** Dealing with exceptions

`Completable.fromRunnable` internally catches exceptions from its `Runnable` and pushes them into the stream as `onError` emissions. However, if you are using Java, you have to deal with checked exceptions inside the `run()` method by yourself. To avoid that you could utilize `Callable` instead of `Runnable`, since its `call()` method's signature declares that it can throw exceptions. `Completable.fromCallable()` wraps exceptions into `onError` emissions as well:

```
Observable.concat(
    someTask, 
    Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Done");
        return null;
    }).toObservable()
);
```

Also `Callable` could be used to create an `Observable` or `Single` with a single item emission.

*P.S.* Check out the source code, these methods are pretty straightforward.

*P.P.S.* [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) has no checked exceptions ;)

---

**Update 2**

There is also `fromAction` factory method for creating `Completable`. It accepts `Action` objects.

> A functional interface similar to Runnable but allows throwing a checked exception.

So the code could be simplified to:

```
Observable.concat(
    someTask, 
    Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }).toObservable()
);
```

Comment: Is there another option that catches any `Throwable` the `Runnable` might throw?